# VBA create csv files

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Save batch files as csv from excel.

VBA separates one Excel sheet of data into separate files, after every 833th row.

Now I need these files to be csvs and not Excels. How can I save directly to .csv (separated by comma) files?

I have made appropriate VBA to save into Excel (xml), but not csvs. I need CSVs.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim rCells As Range
Dim strName As String
Dim lLoop As Long, lCopy As Long
Dim wbNew As Workbook

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set rLastCell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

        For lLoop = 1 To rLastCell.Row Step 833
        lCopy = lCopy + 1
            Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
                .Range(.Cells(lLoop, 1), .Cells(lLoop + 833, .Columns.Count)).EntireRow.Copy _
                    Destination:=wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
            wbNew.Close SaveChanges:=True, Filename:="Chunk" & lCopy & "Rows" & lLoop & "-" & lLoop + 833
        Next lLoop
    End With


End Sub
```

Actual results: Excels
Expected results: CSV files

Comment: Why not try recording a macro while saving a file to CSV, then adjust your code based on that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Sub CSVQuotes()

Dim SrcRange As Range
Dim CurrRow As Range
Dim CurrCell As Range
Dim CurrTextStr As String
Dim ListSeparator As String
Dim FileName As Variant
Dim current As String    

FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename()
ListSeparator = ";"

Set SrcRange = Sheets("DATI").UsedRange

Open FileName For Output As #1
For Each CurrRow In SrcRange.Rows
    CurrTextStr = ""

    For Each CurrCell In CurrRow.Cells
        current = CurrCell

        CurrTextStr = CurrTextStr & """" & current & """" & ListSeparator
    Next
    While Right(CurrTextStr, 1) = ListSeparator
        CurrTextStr = Left(CurrTextStr, Len(CurrTextStr) - 1)
    Wend
    Print #1, CurrTextStr
    Next
Close #1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming:**

`strPath` = path to target folder

`autoIncrement` = variable to increment every loop (so we can differentiate the files names)

`strRow` = string representing 1 row in the CSV; concatenate all columns of each Excel row, alternating values with separator (",")

---

**You can output CSV with this inside a loop:**

```
Open strPath & "\file-" & autoIncrement & ".csv" For Output As #fileNumber
Print #fileNumber, strRow
Close #fileNumber
```